# (Codeigniter) Echo result in view automatic insert to database

Tags: codeigniter, if-statement, model-view-controller, echo

I want echo from if/else conditions (NEW, ALERT, ACTIVE, EXPIRED) automatic input to `tr_status` column in database. What should I do?

[column picture phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdHtk.jpg)

```
        <td>
        <?php
        $today   = Date("Y-m-d");
        $months  = Date("Y-m-d", strtotime('+180 days'));   
        if ($t->tr_no == NULL) {
        echo '<span style="color: #20B2AA; font-weight: bold; ">NEW</span>';
        }

        elseif ($t->tr_exp <= $today) {
        echo '<span style=" color: red; font-weight: bold; ">EXPIRED</span>';
        }

        elseif ($t->tr_exp <= $months) {
        echo '<span style="font-weight: bold; color: ORANGE;">ALERT</span>';
        }
        
        else {
        echo '<span style="font-weight: bold; color: #4DBE24;">ACTIVE</span>';
        }
        ?>    
        </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create a function inside the contoller before load the view file

example :

```
$today   = Date("Y-m-d");
$months  = Date("Y-m-d", strtotime('+180 days'));   

if ($t->tr_no == NULL) {
 $object = array('tr_status' => 'NEW');
}elseif ($t->tr_exp <= $today) {
 $object = array('tr_status' => 'EXPIRED');
} else {
 $object = array('tr_status' => 'ACTIVE');
}

$this->db->insert('Table', $object);
```

Comment: should i make function inside the model?

Comment: u also can do it inside model